# git SHA1 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (all zeroes), is this normal?

Tags: git, sha

I have a yet uncommited branch in git with SHA1 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (all zeroes), is this normal or did I corrupt the git repository?

Please don't answer yes there's one in 2^160, or 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006842277657836021% probabilities to have that SHA1.

I am reasonably safe I'm not the lucky guy who got the SHA1 of 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 in his git repository.

Comment: What is an uncommitted branch? Which git operation produces this value?

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902340/can-a-sha-1-hash-be-all-zeroes

Comment: have you considered mining for bitcoins?

Comment: It would be cool though, if you were.

Comment: probably this is simply indication that there is not a single commit there yet

Comment: Git uses all-zeros as the "null SHA1" meaning "nothing yet".  Most things won't show you the all-zeros value, what did you do that does?  (Hooks see it, for "no previous rev for this ref"; also for "ref deleted".)

Comment: @torek Now I remember. I've seen this hash before, while programming a post-receive hook :-)

Comment: @ Fredrik Pihl you posted the exact thread I didn't want to come up with @ no_answer_not_upvoted ahah good point @ SzG I open gitk to see the current history and for the currently changed but uncommited branch it shows SHA1 000000.. git log doesn't show current branch SHA1 though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A commit includes, among other metadata, the commit date. So the commit hash can't be displayed until the commit has actually been created. What you're seeing is not a commit SHA, it's just a default value used in the UI.

Answer (score 13):

Note, you can find the "all-zeros SHA1" all the way back to [commit f65fdf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f65fdf04a13d2252de8b2b4b161db7c43f2c28ad) (June 30th, 2005, v0.99 of git)

> Linus Torvalds:
>
> A "old ref" of all zeroes is considered a **"don't care" ref**, and allows us to say "write the new ref regardless of what the old ref contained (or even if it existed at all)".
>
> This allows (if git-send-pack were to do it) creating new refs, and fixing up old ones.

---

As [SzG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1323940/szg) mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977462/git-sha1-0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-all-zeroes-is-this-normal#comment28031047_18977462), this is the kind of SHA1 you find in [Git receive/update hooks and new branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3511057/6309), representing an "old-ref" for a non-existent object (while the "new-ref" would create said object, like a branch).