# Is there an especially unlikely SHA1 hash?

Tags: git, sha1, sha

I've got a `Map<SHA1, BinaryBlob>`.  Very similar to Git.

I'd like to put a small, finite number of "special" entries into this map.  I'd like to be able to change the values of the binary blobs, but still refer to them by the same key.

The right way to do this is to use a `Map<Either<SHA1, SpecialKey>, BinaryBlob>`.

The hack way to do this (which is the way I'm actually doing this) is to define:

```
SHA1 specialKeyA = 0x00000 ... 00
SHA1 specialKeyB = 0x00000 ... 01
```

I understand that SHA1 produces values which are evenly distributed.  But I wonder if maybe there's an asterisk, and if there are a couple corner-case hashes (such as `0x00..` or maybe `0xFF...`) which are guaranteed not to happen.

I feel pretty safe with my current design, but I was just curious :)

EDIT: I'm already counting on hash uniqueness, so I feel *very* safe with the design.  The question is for curiosity's sake: are there a handful of values which SHA1 happens to be incapable of generating.  Census in the comments so far seems to be no...

Comment: Fairly sure any such bias would be a flaw that would make reversal much easier/possible.

Comment: Given that it is astronomically unlikely that your "magic hash value" would collide with anything, I'd say "go for it".  It still is a hack.  But let's not overengineer things at this point.

Comment: The answer to your question is **maybe**. SHA1 produces 20-bytes of output; due to the pigeonhole principle every single one of those outputs will be produced within the input range of 0 to 2<sup>64</sup> - 1. If you can store your "hack" as anything *other* then 20-bytes, and do so; then you're done.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Maybe one should add that all SHA1 hashes are equally (un)likely.  So in the given context, while the answer to the question might be "no", the proposed approach is still reasonably safe.

Comment: @Sigi I amended my comment. If you store a magic hash value of anything other then 20-bytes length it can't be a valid SHA1 hash. So, a hash of 21-bytes is **especially** unlikely with SHA1.

Comment: That's correct, and might be the best approach. However, even if you pick any (small) number of "magic" values, the chances that things break because of that are so small that I would say that it's a valid approach in many cases.  If you are aware that it's a hack.

Comment: Adding an analogy: failures because of bad RAM or a meteroid strike are more likely.

Comment: There are 2^160 unique SHA1 values.  If 2 of them (say, the highest and lowest) happened to be impossible, but the function was evenly distributed across all other values, then maybe it would still be a good function.  And it mostly fulfills the pigeonhole principle, except these 2 empty spots that don't matter for real life that only the experts know about.  I'm asking for curiosity's sake if there are any empty spots that maybe only the experts know about.

Comment: If you'd discover such a flaw in SHA1 (that matters in practice) you'd secure a spot in cryptanalysis pantheon.

Comment: Would it matter if SHA1 never produced 0?  E.g. If SHA1 doesn't have any holes, but I made a function called HOLESHA which added 1 to the final result of SHA1 without a carry, thus guaranteeing that zero never happened, it seems you could use HOLESHA in place of SHA just fine.  And so it might be reasonable (knowing nothing about the insides of SHA) that 0 is impossible but SHA is still a good function.

Comment: @Ned unfortunately all bytes 0 is valid and equally likely as any other value (in fact, one property of a secure cryptographic hash is that it can be used to drive a prng).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch given that 00…0 is only the 2^160th part of the range such an imperfection would not hinder its use as a prng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge SHA1 does not have a known pre-image of `00…00` (and neither `00…01`,`00…02`, or other "special" values). Even though it would not violate any of the formal definitions of a secure hash the IVs are designed to avoid such human recognizable patterns.

Still I would probably advise against the use of these values, because others might, too, have come up with the idea to use these special values, see [this question about a git commit with all zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977462/git-sha1-0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-all-zeroes-is-this-normal?rq=1) for example. If it is all the same to you I would generate a random 80bit value, for example `83a…c3`, and append your counter to it, for example `83a…c300…01`, `83a…c300…02`,etc.