# Cannot push repository to GitHub "unable to read 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

This happens to me every time I use GitKraken client.

I am new to Git in general, so please be mind using non - Git jargon :)).

Here are the error code for `git push origin master`.

```
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (637/637), done.
fatal: unable to read 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/NoTalentGeek/xxxxx.git'
```

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18982443/6309